# Player Script cant move right and jump at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity, and I'm writing a player script. Based on the script I've written, I expect to see my player to be able to jump while standing still, while moving left, and while moving right. **The player cant jump if it is moving right at the same time.** I did a bunch of refactoring and reorganizing. I think it might have something to do with `Input.GetButton("Jump")`.

Also, I changed `rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0.0f, jumpHeight))` to `rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0.0f, jumpHeight)`, but the player just disappears.

Here's my script so far:

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
[SerializeField]
private LayerMask whatIsGround;
private bool isTouchingGround;
private bool facingRight = true;

[SerializeField]
private float speed;

[SerializeField]
private float jumpHeight;

[SerializeField]
private Transform[] groundPoints;

[SerializeField]
private float groundRadius;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
}
private void FixedUpdate() {
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Flip(moveHorizontal);
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && IsGrounded()) {
        rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0.0f, jumpHeight));
    }

    rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(moveHorizontal * speed, rb2d.velocity.y);
}

private void Flip(float horizontal) {
    if ((horizontal > 0 && !facingRight) || (horizontal < 0 && facingRight)) {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}

private bool IsGrounded() {
    if (rb2d.velocity.y <= 0) {
        foreach (Transform point in groundPoints) {
            Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(point.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
            foreach (Collider2D collider in colliders) {
                if (collider.gameObject != gameObject)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I'm not sure why it fixed the problem. If you have an idea why, please comment below!

In the `private bool IsGrounded()` method, I removed the `if` statement checking if `rb2d.velocity.y <= 0`. I thought that would be a helpful check to see if the player is moving down or stationary. For some reason, moving the player right was making this if statement fail. This seems like a bug.